# Differentiability of continuous continuation

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a strictly convex, differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=0$ for a $x_0>0$.
Thus $f<0$ on $(0,x_0)$ and $f>0$ on $(x_0,\infty)$.

Let $g(x) = f(x)/(x-x_0)$ on $x\neq x_0$ and assume, that there is a $y_0 \in [0,\infty)$ with
$g(x) \rightarrow y_0$ for $x\rightarrow x_0$.
Define $gx_0 = y_0$.

$g$ is differentiable on $x\neq x_0$ as a composition of differentiable functions.

Is $g$ also differentiable at $x_0$ ? Waht if $y_0 = f'(x_0)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that $f$ is differentiable so $g$ admits a limit at $x_0$ that is $f'(x_0)$.

For the differentiation of $g$ at $x_0$, we have that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if for some $l \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x-x_0} \underset{x \rightarrow x_0}{\longrightarrow} l$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x-x_0} \underset{x \rightarrow x_0}{\longrightarrow} l &\Longleftrightarrow g(x) \underset{x_0}{=} g(x_0) + l(x-x_0) + o(x-x_0) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{f(x)}{x-x_0} \underset{x_0}{=} f'(x_0) + l(x-x_0) + o(x-x_0) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow f(x) \underset{x_0}{=} f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + l(x-x_0)^2 + o((x-x_0)^2) 
\end{align}
that is to say $f$ admits a development at order $2$ at $x_0$. But in general a strictly convex function that is merely differentiable doesn't admit a development at order $2$ at all points. For instance take $f$ defined by $f(x) = e^x$ if $x \leq 0$ and $f(x) = 1+x+x^2$ if $x \geq 0$, you can check that $f$ is differentiable and strictly convex on $\mathbb{R}$ but doesn't admit a development at order $2$ at $0$. So in general we cannot conclude on the fact that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$.